# Customizr slider - strange bug in Firefox only

Tags: css, wordpress, firefox, slider

I'm working on a wordpress site, using the Customizr theme as the base. If you open the page in any browser (not Firefox), it's OK. But in FF, the slider is positioned on the right, outside of the page. I can not find the CSS causing this problem.

Link to the page: http://otterworksgames.com/finalweb/

It seems like the problem is with the .carousel-inner element, but I don't know whats wrong with this CSS snippet (inside an absolute positioned element):

```
.carousel-inner {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

The problem is very annoying, as I need to finish the webside this week. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single line of CSS helped. I put

```
float:left;
```

to the .carousel-inner element, and now it works with Firefox too. Strange, but it works now.